# spring-boot - Conditionally serve static content without template engine

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a static page that I want to conditionally serve on a particular URL.
With spring-boot I can place pages in the `static` or `public` resource directories and have them served to everyone, but if I want to restrict access or disable access to them via a feature flag then this is not suitable.
Using a template engine I can load the page as a template and return a reference to the view. 
However my application is fairly simple and I don't want to utilize a template engine when I otherwise have no need for one.
I want to be able to use a controller to determine weather the page is served or not.
What is the simplest way to have a controller return a static page?

Comment: Create a filter to control access. It's how Spring Security works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I have found to return static content from a controller is to return a [`Resource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html). There are multiple implementations of the `Resource` class but [`ClassPathResource`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/ClassPathResource.html) makes the most sense for a spring-boot app.
In a regular spring-boot application the below example will display `src/main/resources/path/to/mypage.html` when `mycondition()` is `true` and return a 404 otherwise.

```
@RequestMapping("mypage.html")
public Resource myPage() {
    if(mycondition()) {
        return new ClassPathResource("path/to/mypage.html");
    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException();
    }
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
private static class ResourceNotFoundException extends RuntimeException {
    public ResourceNotFoundException() {}
}
```