# How to display a page only, if certain parameters are provided in the URL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, authentication, kotlin

I want to create a page in Spring, which has the url

http://myapp.com/sign-in?email=myemail@provider.com&pw=password

`password` is a one-time password that the user receives via e-mail every time they want to sign in.

Whenever the user visits this page, I want two things to happen:

1. Check whether or not the provided credentials are correct.
2. If they are, display the HTML content of the page.

I've done the first part:

```
    @Autowired
    private var userRepository: UserRepository? = null

    @GetMapping
    fun signIn(@RequestParam email:String, @RequestParam(name="pw") password:String): RedirectView {
        // Is the password correct?

        // TODO: Read password hash of the user
        val existingUser: Optional<UserInfo>? = userRepository?.findById(email)
        if (existingUser == null) {
            return redirectToErrorPage("Please register with your e-mail address first")
        }
        if (!existingUser.isPresent) {
            return redirectToErrorPage("Please register with your e-mail address first")
        }
        val hashInDb = existingUser.get().passwordHash
        val hashInParam = PasswordHashCalculator.calculateHash(password)
        if (!hashInDb.equals(hashInParam)) {
            return redirectToErrorPage("Invalid user name and/or password")
        }

        // TODO: Display the main page
        return null
    }
```

How do I need to change the code in order to display the main page (HTML file in `src/main/resources/static`), but only if the authentication checks are passed?

**Update 1:** Using `return ClassPathResource("main.html")` as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38006022/spring-boot-conditionally-serve-static-content-without-template-engine) did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return ClassPathResource("static/main.html") should answer your question, don't forget to specify `static` folder at the beginning as `ClassPathResource` points to the `resources` folder
```

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't really do your security this way. It's is not good practice to send your password in clear text over http.

There is examples here of basic authentication with spring security.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-basic-authentication

https://www.baeldung.com/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security

What you can do then is, if you follow this tutorial, is assign an in memory user for starters. Then you can Base64Encode your authentication details to the user. Then for each user you can send the authentication details and no one can snoop the username and password as they pass along the wire and your request is dealt with before ever reaching your controller. This way, you can decouple your business logic from your authentication.

That's a start at least. Hope this helps.

Comment: I want to implement authentication that way for a reason. The question is about displaying static content conditionally, not about changing the approach to security.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your reasons so we can help you further? It doesn't really follow to want to implement Spring security that way for any reason. If you absolutely need to do it that way, you can use Controller Advice to throw an exception every time the wrong password is presented to you. How you validate your password is up to you, albeit a database or whatever. To return upon successful validation a web page, do return "index.html" or whatever page you want and this will serve you your page.

Comment: The reason is that I want to create the simplest possible prototype. It would be idiotic to waste a lot of time developing a sophisticated security system, screwring around with Spring security problems, if your program runs only on your local machine. For my **current** purposes, e-mail based authentication is good enough.

Answer (score -1):

@RobScully is right, you should not handle authorization like this . What you can do is enable spring-security and use spring security annotations to handle this scenario.
Use the following dependencies and setup a basic spring security setup.

Annotations like `@PreAuthorize()` can then be used to validate the user privileges before executing a method. You can even add this annotation to controller methods to validate before serving each request if you insist.

You can setup and **LDAP server** or Oauth or even use **database** for authentication (if you working on a demo or something).

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-security.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Use a configuration class like below to configure the security :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

      auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
        .usersByUsernameQuery(
            "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
            "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
    }   

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

      http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')") //To check admin role permission
        .and()
          .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error") //provide failure url
          .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
        .and()
          .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout") 
        .and()
          .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
        .and()
        .csrf();
    }
}
```

This sample project in github gives a basic setup where you can use spring security:

https://github.com/mohchi/spring-security-request-mapping

Reference use:
https://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-form-login-using-database/